# Who are "the Leavers" and "the Remainers"?

Tags: meaning

The context is Brexit and its consequences.

Perhaps this question is obvious, but in my country it is difficult to find information about this topic.
Could you please explain me in short what these people are for?

Comment: It's a bit late now asking what they *are* for, the [referendum took place in **2016**](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum) :) The link directs you to a Wikipedia page written in simple English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It's very much a current issue and people are referred to as presently being one or the other.

Answer (score 12):

These terms refer to the two groups of people who decided the "Brexit" referendum (Should the United Kingdom begin the process to leave the European Union?).

"Leavers" voted for it, that is to leave the EU, and "Remainers" voted against, that is to remain part of the EU.

Comment: That categories aren't exclusive to voters -- they describe what sides people *support*. While the turnout was fairly high there were people who didn't vote, as well as they who for one reason or another couldn't (too young for example)